# Height of div is greater than image

Tags: html, css

I am a rookie for front-end development. Recently, I wrote codes like:

```html
<div style="background-color:red">
        <img src='https://www.logaster.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/jpg.png'>
</div>
```

The height of image(logo.jpg) is 80px, but the height of div is 82px. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image inside div has extra space below the image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Comment: Div height is greater than image, because space around image is pushing div to have that height. Edit your image in photoshop, cut the space up and down image., and it will work! Good luck!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can show image like a block to fix that,

```
<div>
    <img style="display:block" src='logo.jpg'>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: Possible explanation of why this works here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5804278/573110

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="height:your height; width:your witdh;">

 <img src='logo.jpg'>

</div>
```

To change the height or width you can do what i did above with inline style. or give the div a class or give the div an id and style it in an external stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write proper css to achieve this.

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="box1">
    <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/500/500">
   </div>
</div>

.box1 {
 width:auto;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 600px;
 max-height: 300px;
 background-color:chocolate;
 padding:5px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.box1 img {
 vertical-align: top;
 max-width: inherit;
 max-height: inherit;
}
.wrap {
 border: 1px dotted gray;
 margin: 1.00em 0;
 text-align: center;
}
```

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/75nu1a4m/

Comment: Please write a short explanation so that the OP would understand better. Why use this class, etc. It would be really helpful for the OP since he has stated he's a rookie.

Answer (score 0):

```
div
{
     line-height: 0;
     ... 
     img
     {
       ...
     }
}
```

Try: **line-height: 0;**